# Redirect https www to http non-www nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to redirect https to http, and www to non www.
But unfortunately it's not working.

Examples of what i need it to do:

1. https://www.example.com -> http://example.com/
2. http://www.example.com -> http://example.com/

Here is what I've done so far is:

```
# Redirect https to http:
#
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com expample.com;
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
# Redirect www to non-www.
#
server {
    #listen 80 is default
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

# The actual server configuration goes here:
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

#rest of the block configuration
```

Thanks Ahead!

Comment: You have a typo in your first server block: `expample.com`

Comment: Yes, it was a copy-paste error, i don't have it in the server.

Comment: Do you have a certificate for `https://www.example.com`? You are not running an `https` service on port 443 at the moment.

Comment: No i don't have any certificate.